# Getting probability of a certain hand in card game (french tarot)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, card-games

I am trying to figure out the odds of a certain situation in the card game French Tarot, specifically what are the odds of the 'attacker' being out of the same suit of the 'R' that a defender has played on round 1. This is a bad situation since the attacker would win 10 points on the first round.

As a start to this, I want to calculate the odds of any player who takes the dog ending up out of a suit of cards (i.e. having 0 cards of that suit). The dog is a set of 6 cards that the attacker can pick from and must put back 6 cards before starting play.

To calculate this, I want to see the probability that the person has at most 6 of one suit after adding the 6 cars from the dog to their 18 cards (assuming a 4 player game). With 6 or less cards for one suite they can all be placed in the dog, ending up with none of that suit for the final 18 cards before the playing begins.

I wrote the following formula to capture this:

```
C(78-14,24-6)*C(78-(24-6), 6) / C(78,24)
```

The first term [C(78-14,24-6)] represents choosing 18 cards that are not from that suite, and the second term [C(78-(24-6), 6)] represents picking 6 more cars (of any suite) from the remaining cards, which is 78 total minus the first 18. The last term in the division [C(78,24)] represents the total number of hands of 24.

However, when I plug this into Wolfram Alpha I get ~2280 which means my equation is fundamentally wrong since it should be less than 1.0.

If someone can tell me where I am going wrong I'd appreciate it.

Update: I realize that in a real game of French Tarot the attacker who wins the bet is likely to have a better hand than the others, but I am not factoring that in to my calculations at this point, and am assuming an even distribution. Mainly I want to see what is wrong with my equation and then I can build off that.

Update 2: corrected a few typos where I had said 20 and 26 instead of 18 and 24.

Comment: Is 'R' for "roi"?

Comment: Yes, it's for 'or' or King. Rules for the game here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_tarot

Comment: Yes, I found those rules, but was asking since I didn't find an 'R' there. What's 'or' in your comment?

Comment: Sorry I just realized that typo and tried to edit it but couldn't. It should be 'roi' like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that by "at most $6$ of one suit" you mean "at most $6$ of one particular suit" (namely the one whose 'R' the defender plays).

I'll also ignore, like you did, the fact that a defender is known to have played the 'R', so this card is known not to be in the attacker's hand.

Your calculation overcounts hands that have more than $18$ cards not from the given suit (equivalently, hands with less than $6$ cards from that suit). For instance, a hand with $19$ cards not from the given suit is being counted $\binom{19}1=19$ times, since any of the $19$ cards can be taken to be the one in the group of $6$. What you need is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{78-14}{24-k}\binom{14}k\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks. This looks good though I'll wait until I actually get a number to validate before I accept your answer. I need to figure out how to easily input this into wolfram or some other calculation engine.

Comment: @Locksleyu: Interestingly, Wolfram|Alpha accepts $\TeX$ code. It has a weird bug with juxtaposed binomials, which it tends to nest instead of multiplying them. It works if you copy the $\TeX$ code from above (Right/Ctrl-click on the formula, select "Show Math As ... TeX Commands", select all and copy) and insert a '*' between the two binomials before feeding it to Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but getting some crazy number. Can you please confirm if this is what you mean: \sum_{k=0}^6\binom{78-14}{24-k}*\binom{14}k\;.

Comment: I think the problem is that I need to add the denominator, but not sure how to add that to the TEX form.

Comment: @Locksleyu: you don't need the trailing `\;.`. And you can mix styles, so you can add the denominator in $\TeX$ form, or in standard form like this: `\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{78-14}{24-k}*\binom{14}k / binom (78,24)`.

Comment: Thanks, was able to get ~.916 which is a little higher than I expected, but since we are not factoring in the other things I guess it is reasonable. Factoring in the fact one other person has the king would make this number a little higher I think (negligibly), but factoring in the fact that the attacker has the '1' of trumps I am guessing would reduce it by something like (24/(24+18+18+18)) which brings it down to ~.281. Also factoring in the  fact that the suite the attacker is out of is the same as the 'R' played by the other player would reduce things further, but not sure how much.

Comment: Intuitively your explanation about me over counting makes sense, but after some thought I still can't see exactly why my equation is wrong. I actually originally thought to use a summation but then felt it would be cleaner if I could do it w/o one, and ended up with my equation. I'll have to think about it some more and hopefully reach a Eureka moment on why my equation double counts as you said.

Comment: @Locksleyu: In analyzing counts, it's helpful to think of the count in terms of bijections. You're counting selections from subsets, and the count is correct if each such selection corresponds to exactly one of the hands you're trying to count. It doesn't because e.g. each hand with $19$ cards not from the suit corresponds to $19$ different selections, one for each of the $\binom{19}1$ ways of splitting those $19$ cards into $18$ restricted cards and $1$ unrestricted card.